# Capitalize only the first letter with LAMBDA in Excel

Tags: excel, string, excel-formula, capitalization, excel-lambda

In order to capitalize only the first letter of a text I used
`=UPPER(LEFT(A1,1)) & LOWER(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-1))`

With the introduction of `LAMBDA` function in Excel, how can I create a custom lambda function out of it?

Answer (score 3):

**Formulas** -> **Name Manager** -> **New...**

**Name:** fill in the name which will be used to call the function, e.g. UPFIRST
**Refers To:** `=LAMBDA(x, UPPER(LEFT(x,1)) & LOWER(RIGHT(x,LEN(x)-1)))`
[image: lambda function in excel's name manager to capitalize only the first letter in a string]

**OK** to save the custom lambda function.
**Close** to exit the Name Manager.

In the sheet it's called like this:
[image: calling UPFIRST lambda function in excel's sheet]

Answer (score 2):

I suppose there's always the PROPER function....

Comment: `PROPER` will also capitalize the second word, what is not desired.

Answer (score 1):

Nice a first question about `LAMBDA()` =).

Maybe just:

```
=LAMBDA(X,REPLACE(LOWER(X),1,1,UPPER(LEFT(X))))(A1)
```

If you want the "machine" then use `=LAMBDA(X,REPLACE(LOWER(X),1,1,UPPER(LEFT(X))))` in your name manager.